# Ajax php not working

Tags: php, ajax

I am using codeignitor for PHP app development. I was trying ajax call using jquery. But it is not working properly. When I press submit button , same form is reloaded instead of showing alert box. Your help would be very helpful. 
I am sharing code -

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> My Information </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#submit').click(function(){

     // alert('Btn clicked');
     var form_data= {
     username: $('#username').val(),
     address: $('#address').val()       
     };

     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
       url: 'http://localhost/ci-ajax/index.php/user/auth',
      data: form_data,
      success: function(data) {
          $('body').html(data);
      }                          


     });

     });

     });

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
     <label>User Name : </label>
     <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
     <label>Address : </label>
     <input type="text" name="Address" id="address">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
  </form>
 </body>
 </HTML>
```

Controller

```
 Class : user and function auth

 public function auth()
 {
   echo "Welcome";
 }
```

Comment: By the way, you might want to use a slightly more recent version of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You need a way to prevent the submit action. Probably the simplest fix would be to change the input type from `submit` to `button`. If you want something else, you can always `preventDefault` or just `return false` at the end of the function.

Example with `return false;`:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

  // alert('Btn clicked');
  var form_data = {
    username: $('#username').val(),
    address: $('#address').val()
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(data) {
      $('body').html(data);
    }


  });

  return false;

})
```

Comment: And the winner is! This is what will prevent the page reloading & +1 for providing the example :D

Answer (score 1):

in your code, the form has submit input,so when click the submit ,the form will be submited to the server.
So add    **return** in     $('#submit').click(function(){}.
otherwise the form will submit.